# solving min-cut graph using Krager's algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-theory

```
public class Graph
{
    public Graph()
    {
        Vertices = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
    }

    public Dictionary<int,List<int>> Vertices { get; set; }

    public void ApplyKrager()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        while (Vertices.Count > 2)
        {
            
            var randomIndex = random.Next(0,Vertices.Keys.Count);
            var firstVertex = Vertices.Keys.ElementAt(randomIndex);
            var secondVertex = Vertices[firstVertex].ElementAt(random.Next(0,Vertices[firstVertex].Count));
            if (Vertices.ContainsKey(secondVertex))
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Merging " + firstVertex + " " + secondVertex);
                //Merge
                foreach (var edge in Vertices[secondVertex])
                {
                    if (!Vertices[firstVertex].Contains(edge))
                        Vertices[firstVertex].Add(edge);
                }

                //change all the occurences of the secondVertex to the first
                foreach (var vertex in Vertices)
                {
                    if (vertex.Value.Contains(secondVertex))
                    {
                        vertex.Value.Remove(secondVertex);
                        vertex.Value.Add(firstVertex);
                    }
                }
                //Remove Self Loops
                Vertices[firstVertex].RemoveAll(_ => _ == firstVertex);
                Vertices.Remove(secondVertex);
            }
            //Print();
        }

    }

    public void Print()
    {
        foreach (var v in Vertices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Vertex is : " + v.Key);
            Console.Write("Edges are ");
            foreach (var edge in v.Value)
            {
                Console.Write(edge + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

A Test to run this code

```
    [Fact]
    public void CheckForMinimumCuts()
    {
          var input = File.ReadAllLines(@"input.txt");
        var directedEdges = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
        foreach (var line in input)
        {
            var adjacency = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var vertex = Convert.ToInt32(adjacency[0]);
            var edges = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < adjacency.Length; i++)
            {
                edges.Add(Convert.ToInt32(adjacency[i]));
            }

            directedEdges.Add(vertex, edges);
        }

        var cuts = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            var graph = new Graph {Vertices = directedEdges};
            graph.ApplyKrager();
            foreach (var v in graph.Vertices)
            {
                cuts.Add(v.Value.Count);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(cuts.Min());
    }
```

//input.txt

```
1 3 4 2
2 1 4 3
3 1 2 4
4 5 3 2 1
5 4 8 6 7
6 8 7 5
7 5 8 6
8 5 7 6

expected result: 1
cut is [(4,5)]
```

The algorithm above does not give my correct output, even when run several times achieve randmisation.

Is my choice of random edges somehow skewed ?

Should I be doing cuts.Add(graph.Vertices.first().count() instead ?

Or is my algorithm coded incorrectly and hence no chance of correct output ?

Note: tried to mark this question as homework..couldn't find the tag.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a service for debugging your buggy code. The way to solve the problem is: choose a small example that fails. Write down *on paper* the exact actions a correct implementation would perform. Then watch your program in the debugger. The first time it does an action different than the one you wrote down, there's the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The randomised-contraction minimum-cut algorithm requires that you uniformly randomly choose an **edge**.  You are uniformly randomly choosing a vertex and then uniformly randomly choosing an edge incident with that vertex.

You probably also have an implementation error that I can't see because I don't know C#.  I would be surprised if 500 iterations of your algorithm on an 8-vertex graph failed to identify the minimum cut.  Does `new Random()` produce a RNG with the same seed every time, perhaps?

Comment: `new Random()` seeds off the number of milliseconds since the machine was last rebooted, which can easily produce an identical series; you can create a lot of objects in one millisecond.

Comment: @EricLippert: Then there's the (major) bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake in the block

```
//change all the occurences of the secondVertex to the first.
```

Change the `if(!Vertices[firstVertex].Contains(edge))` to `while(!Vertices[firstVertex].Contains(edge))`, otherwise the replacement only occurs once.