# How to implement Karger's min cut algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to implement Karger's min cut algorithm but I am unable to get the correct answer. Can someone please have a look at my code and help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Would really appreciate the help.

```
package a3;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Graph {

private ArrayList<Integer>[] adjList;
private int numOfVertices = 0;
private int numOfEdges = 0;


public Graph(String file) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream wordsFile = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(wordsFile));
    adjList = (ArrayList<Integer>[]) new ArrayList[201];
    for (int i = 1; i < 201; i++) {
        adjList[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
    while (true) {

        String s = br.readLine();

        if (s == null)
            break;
        String[] tokens = s.split("\t");
        int vertex = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
        this.numOfVertices++;

        for (int i = 1; i < tokens.length; i++) {

            Integer edge = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
            addEdge(vertex, edge);
            this.numOfEdges++;

        }

    }
}

public void addEdge(int v, int w) {
    adjList[v].add(w);
    //this.numOfEdges++;

}

public ArrayList<Integer> getNeighbors(Integer v) {
    return adjList[v];
}

public boolean hasEdge(Integer i, Integer j) {
    return adjList[i].contains(j);
}

public boolean removeEdge(Integer i, Integer j) {
    if (hasEdge(i, j)) {
        adjList[i].remove(j);
        adjList[j].remove(i);
        this.numOfEdges -= 2;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public int getRandomVertex(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    return (rand.nextInt(this.getNumOfVertices()) + 1);
}

//Returns an array which consists of vertices connected by chosen edge
public int[] getRandomEdge(){
    int arr[] = new int[2];
    arr[0] = this.getRandomVertex();
    while (adjList[arr[0]].size() == 0) {
        arr[0] = this.getRandomVertex();            
    }

    Random rand = new Random();
    arr[1] = adjList[arr[0]].get(rand.nextInt(adjList[arr[0]].size()));
    return arr;
}

//Algorithm for min cut
public int minCut() {
    while (this.getNumOfVertices() > 2) {
        int[] edge = this.getRandomEdge();
        this.removeEdge(edge[0], edge[1]);
        //Adding edges of second vertex to first vertex
        for (Integer v: adjList[edge[1]]) {
            if (!adjList[edge[0]].contains(v)) {
                addEdge(edge[0], v);
            }               
        }

        //Removing edges of second vertex
        for (Iterator<Integer> it = adjList[edge[1]].iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Integer v = it.next();
            it.remove();
            this.numOfEdges--;
        }

        //Removing self-loops
        for (Iterator<Integer> it = adjList[edge[0]].iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Integer v = it.next();
            if (v == edge[0]) 
                it.remove();
                //this.numOfEdges--;
        }

        this.numOfVertices--;

    }
    return this.numOfEdges;
}

public int getNumOfVertices() {
    return this.numOfVertices;
}

public int getNumOfEdges() {
    return (this.numOfEdges) / 2;
}

public String toString() {

    String s = "";
    for (int v = 1; v < 201; v++) {
        s += v + ": ";
        for (int e : adjList[v]) {
            s += e + "-> ";
        }
        s += null + "\n";
        //s += "\n";
    }
    return s;
}

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int min = 1000;
    //Graph test = new Graph("C:\\Users\\UE\\Desktop\\kargerMinCut.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Graph test = new Graph("C:\\Users\\UE\\Desktop\\kargerMinCut.txt");
        int currMin = test.minCut();
        min = Math.min( min, currMin );            
    }

    System.out.println(min);
}

}
```

Comment: What output/error are you getting?

Comment: i am not getting the correct answer for minimum cut. the answer should be 17 but i am getting answers that are greater than 200. i am pretty sure my mistake is in the minCut function where i am not keeping track of the number of edges correctly.

Comment: Coursera homework? :)
I've noticed a couple of errors:
* When adding edges from the second node to the first one you shouldn't check for its presence. Karger algorithm relies on multigraphs.
* You should not simply remove all edges of the second node. You should "relink" it to the first one.
* Why are you manually tracking `numOfEdges` at all? Simply merge nodes while there are only two left and return the number of edges from any of them left.
Here is a description http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger's_algorithm and a gist with java https://gist.github.com/MastaP/2314166

Comment: possible duplicate of [solving min-cut graph using Krager's algorithm in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777054/solving-min-cut-graph-using-kragers-algorithm-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Yury: yes, coursera homework. i will look into ur suggestions....can u explain how i can relink the edges of second vertex to the first one??
can i come back to u if i have more questions?

Comment: @ueg1990: Smth like this `for(node in adjList[second]){ adjList[node].replaceAll(second, first)}`.

Comment: hi Yury, i had one more question abt the implementation of my undirected graph: when i implement the addEdge fucntion, should i add add to both nodes? as in for vertex u and v, should i do both adjList[u].add(v) and adjList[v].add(u) or only the first one???

Comment: I did this problem. Had to do it twice since my 1st implementation didn't work. You can read how I solved it here: http://www.zenskg.net/wordpress/?p=415